# Change handler not called on radio input on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, input, radio-button, onchange

I've distilled the issue down to this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/shaggyfrog/DUqYW/3/

On Chrome/Mac and Safari/Mac, you should get the "foo" alert every time you (re)load the page.

On Firefox/Mac, the "foo" alert only comes up the first time. Subsequent reloads do not trigger it.

This is either: (A) a bug in jQuery on Firefox, where a change handler on a radio input should get called irrespective of its state when it's checked; (B) a different jQuery bug, where the change handler should not be called if it's already checked; or (C) me doing something stupid.

Is this a legitimate bug or am I a legitimate n00b?

Comment: Your JSFiddle is working for me in FF 5 on Windows, so this would only apply to FF on Mac. Regarding doing something stupid. You didn't click on "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs", did you?

Comment: @Semyazas working the first time, or even after reloading the page? I'm running FF 3.6.19 on my Mac. Shift-reloading the page works, but not "normal" reloading.

Comment: Even after reloading without shift.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload, Firefox preserves the checked state of radios from before the reload, so your script clicks an input that is already checked... and hence there is no value change.