# $(document).on("change") not fire up on Mozilla Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue with radio button and jquery. The onchange is working in Chrome but is not working in Mozilla Firefox. I put a breakpoint on the line below on Chrome and the browser is debugging normally, but when I am on Mozilla, this onchange never fires up

```
$(document).on("change", 'input[type="radio"]', function () {//code for doing something}
```

My HTML code is

```
<div id="tab-Pcy-2041" class="tab-pane active">
    <div class="radio radio-small">
        <label class="">
            <div class="i-radio checked">
                <input class="i-radio" data-ano="1" data-chno="0" 
                data-adce="0" data-chce="0" data-for="rbtncy"
                 xname="rbcy204" name="rbtncy2040" value="22038"
                 checked="checked" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" type="radio" />
                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left:   0%; 
                 display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
                 background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 
                 0px none; opacity: 0;">
                </ins>
            </div>
        test
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio radio-small">
        <label class="">
            <div class="i-radio">
                <input class="i-radio" data-ano="1" data-chno="0" 
                 data-ace="15" data-chce="15" 
                 data-for="rbtncy" xname="rbtncy204"
                 name="rbtncy2040" value="22039" 
                 style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" type="radio" />
                <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: 
                 absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; 
                 margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) 
                 none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;">
                </ins>
            </div>
            test33:
            <span class="ItemtestClass" data-itemce="15">
                <span class="CurrencySymbolClass">€</span>
                <span class="Itce"> 15</span>
            </span>
            Cd:
            <span class="ItemtestClass" data-itemce="15">
                <span class="CurrencySymbolClass">€</span>
                <span class="Itemce"> 15</span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say Mozilla you mean Firefox right?

Comment: What versions of Chrome/Firefox are you using? also what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of firefox?

Comment: Can you test this fiddle and tell me if it is working in Firefox please? 
https://jsfiddle.net/8yq7rgv6/

Comment: I am using 
jQuery v1.10.1
Firefox 50.1.0

Comment: Ninigi yes it is working

Comment: In that case, could you please post your html with this? Maybe there is something chrome does handle different than firefox. :)

Comment: Yes Please paste your html code as well

Comment: Please post your full code, it doesnt look like there is any issue with the Javascript. As you say it doesnt work but we dont know what its supposed to do.

Comment: Related?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856556/change-handler-not-called-on-radio-input-on-firefox  (to do with reloading the page)

Comment: try `$(window)`

Comment: And what is your change event supposed to do?

Comment: just an alert alert('test');

Answer (score 0):

With minimal markup and script you can refer to the working snippet below

```js
$(document).on("change","input[type=radio]", function(){
  console.log($(this).prop("id"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="option1" /><label for="option1">Option 1</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="option2" /><label for="option2">Option 2</label><br />
<input type="radio" name="rd1" id="option3" /><label for="option3">Option 3</label><br />
```

Comment: which version of firefox are you using? I have mine working fine 48.0.2 on Windows